# Setting background color for relativelayout

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

When I set background color of a relativelayout, color of the components inside the layout also takes shade of the layout color. For example, if I set the layout color as blue, all the components gets a blue shade. Can anybody help me ?

Comment: Can you post a picture? This shouldn't be happening unless you widgets have a partial opacity.

Comment: Hi, can post more details about your Layout or post your .xml

Answer (score 0):

Do you added background color to the components?

Comment: No. I have not set any background color for components. The layout has only buttons in it.

Comment: maybe your  backgrounds of components are transparent, you should set the backgrounds for components as well.

Comment: maybe your  components`s background are transparent, you should set the components`s  backgrounds  as well.